# Change Width of Element via scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to achieve an affect like you can see here: http://www.nearme.co.il/Code/index.htm (if it's not working in Chrome try IE).

This is what I achieved so far: http://jsfiddle.net/yuvalsab/op9sg2L2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="trasition_wrapper">
    <div class="trasition">1</div>
    <div class="trasition">2</div>
    <div class="trasition">3</div>
    <div class="trasition">4</div>
    <div class="trasition">5</div>
    <div class="trasition">6</div>
    <div class="trasition">7</div>
    <div class="trasition">8</div>
    <div class="trasition">9</div>
    <div class="trasition">10</div>
    <div class="trasition">11</div>
    <div class="trasition">12</div>
    <div class="trasition">13</div>
    <div class="trasition">14</div>
    <div class="trasition">15</div>
</div>
<div class="pagewrap">
    <div class="some_text_1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="some_text_2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="some_text_3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="some_text_4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="some_text_5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="some_text_6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="some_text_7">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="some_text_8">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="some_text_9">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="some_text_10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="some_text_11">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="some_text_12">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="some_text_13">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="some_text_14">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div[class^="some_text"] {   
    padding:50px 0;
    border-bottom:1px solid;
}
div.trasition_wrapper {
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
    left:100%;
    background:red;
}
.trasition {
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
function animate(element) {
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    window_width = $(window).innerWidth();
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        var scrolltop = $(this).scrollTop();
        var stcalc = $(this).scrollTop()*3; // 3 -> Sets the speed of the animation
        if(stcalc >= window_width) {
            stcalc = window_width;
        }
        if(stcalc < window_width) {
           element.animate({
                left:-stcalc
            }, 10);
        } 
        else {
            stcalc = window_width;
            element.animate({
                left:-stcalc
            }, 10);
        }
        lastScrollTop = scrolltop;
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.trasition_wrapper .trasition').each(function() {
        var element = jQuery(this);
        pos=0;
        position = pos+40;
        animate(element);
        element.css('top',position+'px');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a decent solution. It could be cleaned up a bit, but it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/scheda/4tsokks7/

```
$(document).on('scroll', function(e) {
    var bodyHeight = $(document).height()
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    var whereAmI = scrollTop + windowHeight

    //we need to make sure we're calculating the percentage correctly
    if (scrollTop < windowHeight) {
        var heightPercentage = scrollTop / bodyHeight * 100;
    } else {
        var heightPercentage = whereAmI / bodyHeight * 100;
    }

    $('.scroll-progress').css('width', heightPercentage + '%');
    $('.progress').text(Math.round(heightPercentage));
});
```

It's pretty simple. Basically it just calculates where you are in your scroll and then updates `.scroll-progress` with a new width and text.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I'm looking for... see http://www.nearme.co.il/Code/index.htm

Comment: That doesn't work on Firefox or Chrome. I checked out the fiddle you passed over and it looked like you were looking for an expanding thing like that. You can use this as a template to add any data you want into the bar.

Comment: You're right, but it does work in Internet Explorer (it's a very old example, but it's the only one I found)...

Comment: Can you better explain what you're trying to do in your main post then? Are you looking for something different in the bar or... Something else? Describing the effect will help those of us who don't have access to IE all the time.